# Convert nanocore to core CPU?

Tags: kubernetes, cpu-cores

im confuse to convert nanocore to core of CPU
my formula is:

`nanocore / 1000000000 = CORE (1000000000 is 1 billion)`

if my linux os have 10 core.
I want to calculator percentage cpu usage. This formula is:

`(nanocore / 1000000000) / 10 * 100 = percentage cpu usage ?`

is it right ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a core is equal to 1e9 (1,000,000,000) nanocores.

You can test this by seeing that, for example in Datadog, a metric like `(kubernetes.cpu.usage.total / 1000000000) / kubernetes_state.node.cpu_allocatable * 100` gives you a percentage that should be capped at 100%. The 1st metric is measured in nanocores, and the 2nd is measured in cores ([see definition here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/containers/kubernetes/data_collected/)).

Here's another answer that aligns with this: [link](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/metric-server-cpu-and-memory-units/7497/2)